# Python thread execution blocking other threads

Tags: python, multithreading, execution

Both threads work if accessed  but when they are executed together `halt_listener` will monopolize the resources not allowing `import_1` to execute. The end goal is to have halt_listener listen for a kill message and then set a run variable to false. This has worked when I was sending a pipe to the halt_listener but I prefer a queue.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 
from threading import Thread

class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      alive = {'import_1': True, 'import_2': True};

      def halt_listener(self, control_Queue, thread_Name, kill_command):
          while True:
              print ("Checking queue for kill")
              isAlive = control_queue.get()
              print ("isAlive", isAlive)
              if isAlive == kill_command:
                 print ("kill listener triggered")
                 self.alive[thread_Name] = False;
                 return

      def import_1(self, control_Queue, thread_Number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_Number
          halt = test_imports()
          t = Thread(target=halt.halt_listener, args=(control_Queue, 'import_1', 't1kill'))
          count = 0 
          t.run()
          global alive 
          run = test_imports.alive['import_1'];
          while run:
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_Number, count)
                count = count + 1
                print ("Test Import_1 ", run)
                run = self.alive['import_1'];
          print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_Number
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: As a side note: I notice you're also importing multiprocessing, even though you aren't using it in your sample code. If you want to use `multiprocessing` and `threading` at the same time, it's a very bad idea to use `from … import …`, because that makes it way too easy to accidentally pass a `threading.Lock` or `queue.Queue` to a process instead of a `multiprocessing.Lock` or `multiprocessing.Queue`…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `t.run()`. `run` isn't a method that starts a thread; `run` is the actual code that's meant to run on the thread. By calling it directly, you're running it on *your* thread, and waiting for it to finish.

What you want is `t.start()`.

See the documentation on [`threading.Thread`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) for details.

---

While we're at it, there are a few other problems with your code.

First, you don't have a lock around `self.alive`. You can't change a value (except for a small number of automatically-self-synchronized types like `Queue`) in one thread and access it in another without a lock. You will often get away with it, but "often" in a multithreaded program just means it won't fail until your big demonstration, and it will then take weeks to figure out how to reproduce before you can even begin fixing it… (In this case, a Condition might make more sense than a Lock, but either way, you need to synchronize on *something*.)

Meanwhile, looping as fast as possible to poll `self.alive['import_1']` is going to burn 100% CPU for no good reason. There's almost always a better way to wait on something (e.g., in this case, if you used a Condition for synchronization, you could also use it for waiting here); in the rare cases when there isn't, you should at least `sleep` every time through the loop.

`alive` is actually a class attribute rather than an instance attribute. That's usually not what you want. In fact, you try to access both `test_imports.alive` and `self.alive`, but both of those will end up being the class attribute as long as you never assign to it, which makes it more confusing. And then, on top of that, you have a global with the same name, which is just a recipe for extreme confusion.

Also, this looks like Python 2 code, but you're using `print` as if it were a function in some cases—e.g., `print ("isAlive", isAlive)`. This isn't going to do what you want—instead of printing something like `isAlive command`, it's going to print something like `('isAlive', 'command')`, which is not very pretty. And meanwhile, the extra parentheses in expressions like `("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_Number` mean that someone has to read that over a few times to convince themselves that the parentheses aren't actually doing anything.

Finally, why are you creating a separate `test_imports` instance to call `halt_listener` on? Clearly the two methods are trying to communicate through attributes on `self`, but they're not going to do that if they're called on two different objects. Why not just `target=self.half_listener`?

Comment: Understood, I am still just playing around. Thanks for all the advice I am gonna be implementing it all. It is very much appreciated!

Comment: It will start and stop properly when running 2 threads but when I run more it seems to have issues. Is this the locking issue presenting? What would be a good example of a lock and how to share it?

Comment: Well, without knowing what issues it has, it's hard to say. But most likely it's having a thread (or maybe lots of threads?) looping as fast as possible to check the same variable over and over that's causing problems. Meanwhile, a good example of a lock would be `my_lock = threading.Lock()`. You share it the same way as any other value—an instance member, a global, a parameter, whatever. Then, every time you want to modify or access `self.alive`, you put `with my_lock:` around it, and that's it. For more details, read the docs, because I can't explain things any better than they can.

Comment: One last thing: If you have a bunch of threads that are all trying to do CPU-intensive work, Python does not handle that well. Having a bunch of threads reading from the disk, making network requests, responding to user events, etc., that's all fine, but having a bunch of threads factoring prime numbers is not; instead of getting 4x faster with 4 threads, it'll get 25% slower. If that's the kind of thing you're trying to do, you want `multiprocessing`, not `threading`.